# Printing Linked Lists

Tags: c

Im trying to print variables that assigned in the nodes but it prints random data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
};

int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;

    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head -> data = 1;
    head -> next = second;

    second -> data = 2;
    second -> next = third;

    third-> data = 3;
    third -> next = NULL;


    printf("%d",head);
    printf("\n%d",second); //problem in this part
    printf("\n%d",third);




    return 0;
```

I'm expecting an output like 1,2,3 which are variables that I assigned to.

Comment: What *is* `head` and `second` and `third`? Are they integer variables containing the values you expect?

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: ` head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  to have both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred output to `stderr`

Comment: The posted code does not compile! It is missing a final closing brace '}'. There are three statements like: `printf("%d",head);` where the parameter is a pointer to a `struct node *` but the `%d` is expecting a pointer to a `int`   The result is the address of the struct instance is being printed rather than the contents of the struct field `data`.  Suggest: `printf( "%d\n", head->data );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the pointer, i.e. the address of those structures.
if you want to print data you should print the data field:

```c
printf("%d", head->data);
```

also, if you want to print out all the elements of a singly linked list, you can do this:

```c
struct Node* p = head;
while (p != NULL)
{
  printf("%d\n", p->data);
  p = p->next;
}
```